# socket.io: how to make server run functions when disconnection from a room

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Trying to learn socket io and I'm playing around with a test application where:

- Sockets join different rooms depending on the page url (/page1 connections join room page1, etc)
- I have a separate 'dashboard' page which I want to show how many connections are from each page

I have two problems (the documentation is confusing me):

- When a user disconnects, I don't know how to determine which room they were in and hence do different functions depending on the room.

Here is my attempt:

**Server Code**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('joinRoom', function(room){
        console.log('New connection to room: ' + room);
        socket.join(room);  // Clients join different rooms depending on the page.
        console.log(socket.rooms);  // socket.rooms here has a value
        // code to increment room counter will go here.
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){

        console.log(socket.rooms); // In this line, socket.rooms is EMPTY
        if (socket.rooms == room1){
            // decrement room 1 counter
        }

    });
});
```

**Client Code**

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('joinRoom', 'client');
});
```

- My next problem, I can't seem to get the right syntax for the client to emit to a room / the server to react to messages coming from a specific room. If someone could give me an example to follow it would be extremely helpful.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hey, what version of socket.io are you using? The syntax actually depends because they've been updating their room API through version changes. If you're not sure, run `npm list` in your server's folder and look at the number after `socket.io@`

Answer (score 0):

Upon join you need to "register" the room for the socket like the following:

```
currentRoom[socket.id] = room.newRoom;
```

and when they leave just call:

```
socket.leave(currentRoom[socket.id]);
```

this should do.